# Clojure - Applying a Function to a vector of vectors

Tags: clojure

I have a vector `[[[1 2] [3 4]] [[5 6] [7 8]] [9 10] 11]`. I want to apply a function to this vector but keep the data structure.

For example I want to add 1 to every number but keep the data structure to get the result being `[[[2 3] [4 5]] [[6 7] [8 9]] [10 11] 12]`. Is this possible?

I have tried

```
(map #(+ 1 %) (flatten [[[1 2] [3 4]] [[5 6] [7 8]] [9 10] 11]))
=> (2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12)
```

But you can see that the data structure is not the same.

Is there maybe a function that takes `(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12)` to `[[[2 3] [4 5]] [[6 7] [8 9]] [10 11] 12]`

I thought maybe to use postwalk but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 6):

You can use `postwalk`:

```
(require '[clojure.walk :as walk])

(let [t [[[1 2] [3 4]] [[5 6] [7 8]] [9 10] 11]]
  (walk/postwalk (fn [x] (if (number? x) (inc x) x)) t))
```

Answer (score 4):

also the classic recursive solution is not much more difficult:

```
(defn inc-rec [data]
  (mapv #((if (vector? %) inc-rec inc) %) data))
#'user/inc-rec

user> (inc-rec [1 [2 3 [4 5] [6 7]] [[8 9] 10]])
;;=> [2 [3 4 [5 6] [7 8]] [[9 10] 11]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve your problem is via [Specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter). You do need another dependency then, but it can be a helpful library.

```
(ns your-ns.core
  (:require [com.rpl.specter :as specter]))

(def data [[[1 2] [3 4]] [[5 6] [7 8]] [9 10] 11])

(specter/defprotocolpath TreeWalker) ;; define path walker
(specter/extend-protocolpath TreeWalker
                             ;; stop walking on leafs (in this case long)
                             Object nil
                             ;; when we are dealing with a vector, TreeWalk all elements
                             clojure.lang.PersistentVector [specter/ALL TreeWalker])
```

You can extend it to perform more complicated operations. For this use case normal Clojure is good enough.

```
(specter/transform [TreeWalker] inc data)
;; => [[[2 3] [4 5]] [[6 7] [8 9]] [10 11] 12]
```